# Which actor has the highest difference in ratings?

Tags: sql, database, video, difference, highest

I need further help with my SQL problem.

In this database on movies, ratings and actors: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qFIbC.jpg

I am required to find the actor who has the largest difference between their best and their worst rated movie.

The condition is that the ratings cannot be lower than 3! (>3)
My current SQL looks as follows:

```
SELECT * FROM stars
JOIN ratings ON stars.movie_id = ratings.movie_id
WHERE ratings.movie_id = (
    SELECT MAX(rating) - MIN(rating) FROM ratings
    WHERE rating > 3);
```

My expectations were that I would get somewhat of a result in my Github terminal that I can work with to adjust my SQL query.

But I seem to have reached a dead-end and I'm not sure how to solve this solution

Comment: Please don't upload images, but provide both sample input and expected outcome as tables.

Comment: To solve this you need to follow 2 logical steps 1) For each actor, find the difference between their best and worst rating 2) From this information, find which actor has the greatest difference. Your existing SQL is a step in the right direction to solving 1) so it shouldn't take much to get that to work; then you can solve 2)

Answer (score 0):

You need to `GROUP BY` actor to calculate everyone's rating range. Then, take the actor with the largest range. Something like this:

```
SELECT
    person_id,
    MAX(rating) - MIN(rating) AS rating_range
FROM
    stars
    JOIN ratings ON stars.movie_id = ratings.movie_id
WHERE
    rating > 3
GROUP BY
    person_id
ORDER BY
    2 DESC
LIMIT
    1
;
```

Comment: GROUP BY worked like a charm! I appreciate the help John K, thanks.